# How we use dot net dll in mono?

Tags: .net, dll, mono

i have already dot net DLL which should work in Linux mono .

Mono Develop is an open source integrated development environment for Linux, Mac OS, and Windows. Its primary focus is development of projects that use Mono and .NET frameworks

Answer (score 0):

.net and Mono are similar but not identical. You could decompile the dll into some c#, which you could then compile in Mono.

Another option would be to run wine on the Linux machine, but that's a lot of fudge and effort. Recompiling so 'the whole thing' is in Mono would be cleaner.

You can theoretically reference the .net dll directly from Mono, but if that dll relies on anything that mono can't fake, it'll fail.